# Spring Reactor with REST Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, reactor

I am trying to achieve Spring Reactor using Rest Service.
Controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;


@RestController
public class CustomerController {


    @Autowired
    private FluxService fluxService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/handleMessageReactor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Flux<MessageAcknowledgement> handleMessage(@RequestBody Customer message) {
        return fluxService.fluxMethod(message);
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
package com.nbcu;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
@Service
public class FluxService {

    MessageAcknowledgement msg;
    public Flux fluxMethod(Customer cust)
    {

        System.out.println("Name"+cust.getName());
        System.out.println("Address"+cust.getAddress());
        msg=new MessageAcknowledgement("Success");
        return Flux.just(msg);

    }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nbcu</groupId>
    <artifactId>Report</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringReactor</name>
    <description>Spring Reactor POC</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectreactor/reactor-spring -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is the below compilation Error am getting:

```
INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringReactor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ Report ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Workspace\SpringReactor\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Report ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Report ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to D:\Workspace\SpringReactor\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringReactor/src/main/java/com/nbcu/FluxService.java:[5,30] package reactor.core.publisher does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringReactor/src/main/java/com/nbcu/FluxService.java:[10,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Flux
  location: class com.nbcu.FluxService
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringReactor/src/main/java/com/nbcu/CustomerController.java:[9,30] package reactor.core.publisher does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringReactor/src/main/java/com/nbcu/CustomerController.java:[21,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Flux
  location: class com.nbcu.CustomerController
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringReactor/src/main/java/com/nbcu/FluxService.java:[16,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Flux
  location: class com.nbcu.FluxService
[INFO] 5 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.329 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-02T15:15:50+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Anyone please help me to resolve why I am getting this compilation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a reactor version that does not contain the `Flux` and `Mono` operators.

Because Spring 5 and Boot 2.0 aren't released yet, the easiest way to try the new web reactive framework in Spring is to:

- try [the experimental Boot starter](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-boot-web-reactive)
- or [bootstrap things manually as explained in Spring's reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-getting-started-manual)

Answer (score 7):

You can look at [compile dependencies needed for Spring Reactor](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectreactor/reactor-spring/1.0.0.RELEASE) the transitive dependency reactor-core-1.1.6-RELEASE doesn't contain `reactor.core.publisher` package.

I think you should include this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Infact into the [reactor-core](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/tree/master/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher) you can find the `Flux` class you're searching for

Answer (score 2):

You need to change dependency like below

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of this

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```